# Javascript Regex match everything except double spaces then replace

Tags: javascript, regex, match, whitespace

I need a regex that will match anything except white spaces or only words in between double spaces.

Like :

let's assume the `underscores` where equal to `spaces` just for example.

`foo_bar__The_Quick_Dog__is_addicted_to___jumping___`

Then `replace` the `spaces` with any `symbol`, preferably a `Comma (,)`.

So we should have: **foo bar, The Quick Dog, is addicted to, jumping.**

However, the word *jumping* should NOT have it's white spaces replaced with `comma` because it's at the end... adding a `comma` to it will be meaningless

I tried:

```
/\(\s*([^)]+?)\s*\)/
```

and

```
[a-z].\s{2,}.*
```

and

```
\s\s.*[a-z]
```

and

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])+[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

and a few hundreds more... still no good.

Thank

Comment: I'm confused there is a `Coma` after `is addicted to`, but there is only a single space between `to` and `jumping`

can you try to clarify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you mean like this?

```
var str = 'foo bar  The Quick Dog  is addicted to  jumping   ';
str.replace(/\s\s+/g, ', ').replace(/, (\n|$)/g, '.$1');
"foo bar, The Quick Dog, is addicted to, jumping."
```

Replace multi-spaces with *"comma space"*, then replace *"comma space new line"* or *"comma space end"* with *"full stop new line"* or *"full stop end"*, respectively.

Comment: AMAZING! Please can you explain this part? `(\n|$)/g`

Comment: `(\n|$)` is _"new line" OR "end"_ in a capture group. `/` ends the pattern and `g` is the _global_ flag.

Comment: Works like VOODOO!...That's Super Good, I owe you a Burger :)

Comment: Man is the 3(rd) arguments in `String.replace(1,2,3)` a good practice? i.e `.replace(/, (\n|$)/g, '.$1')` `$1` is a third argument.

Comment: @ErickBest there is no 3rd arg, only two; the first comma is inside the _RegExp_ literal

Comment: Cool Man... My Eyes didnt know how to see better at 4:30am that day... just Confirmed, it is 2 args only!.. Thanx again.

Answer (score 1):

Using a replacer ([mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) :

```
var s = 'foo bar  The Quick Dog  is addicted to jumping  ';
s.replace(/ {2,}(.)?/g, function (m, p) { return p ? ', ' + p : '.'; });
// prints "foo bar, The Quick Dog, is addicted to jumping."
```

Using `match` + `join`. This one also trims out the leading whitespaces :

```
var s = '   foo bar  The Quick Dog  is addicted to jumping  ';
var m = s.match(/[^ ]+( [^ ]+)*/g);
m && (m.join(', ') + '.'); // null OR join()
// prints "foo bar, The Quick Dog, is addicted to jumping."
```

`match` + `join` inside a function :

```
function fix(str, separator) {
    var m = str.match(/[^ ]+( [^ ]+)*/g);
    return m && (m.join(separator || ', ') + '.');
}

var s = ' ab cd   ef   gh ';
fix(s); // "ab cd, ef, gh."
fix(s, ' - '); // "ab cd - ef - gh."
fix(' '); // null
```

Comment: Thax man.. though the solution by @Paul S. really worked well cause it magically adds the fullstop at the end, while it trims out the trailing white spaces. That was what I really wanted.

Comment: Thax a million... Could you please explain the what the two arguments in the `function` stand for?  the `m` and the `p`...?

Comment: @wared If you're using a function, why not keep your look-ahead style?  `/( {2,}(?!$|\n))|( {2,}(?=$|\n))/g` with `function ($0, $1, $2) {if ($1) return ', '; return '.';}`

Comment: @ErickBest See the "match + join" sample. It also trims out the leading whitespaces.